# Problems with JSCH and multithreaded java app

Tags: java, multithreading, jsch

I am trying to execute multiple commands remotely thru multithreaded java app.
I am using JSCH for that and having problem with it.

Sometimes it runs fine and sometimes it just gives me error code of '-1' and does not log anything. I am not able to figure out why it's failing because it's not logging anything when it returns '-1'. Below is the code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();  
Session session;
int exitCode = 0;
try {
    String cmd = "command";
    session = jsch.getSession("usrName", "machineName");        
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setPassword("pwd");
    session.connect(500);
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) channel;
    channelExec.setCommand("cmd.exe /c "+cmd);
    channel.connect();          
    InputStream is = channel.getInputStream();
    log.info(convertISToString(is));
    exitCode = channel.getExitStatus();
    System.out.println(exitCode);
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();       
} catch (JSchException e) {
    log.info(e)
    return 1;
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.info(e);
    return 1;
}
return exitCode;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a different `JSch` object in each thread or shared.  Might try one per object.  Any information in the server logs to explain the -1 every once and a while?

Comment: And when you say it returns `-1` you mean from the `ChannelExec.getExitStatus()`?

Comment: Yes its one per object, whole posted code is inside a method which gets called from run(). -1 is from Channel exitStatus. Can you please tell me where in the server logs I should be looking info?

Comment: I'd take a look at the syslog output from sshd to see if you see anything.  Depends on how the sshd is configured as to where that goes.

Comment: I cannot see anything in the log.

Comment: Huh.  You should log the exact time you get the -1 and enable syslog output on the server and see if you can see if it connected but somehow failed or some other issue?

Comment: Are you sure the process is actually finished?  channel.getExitStatus() will return -1 if the process is not actually finished.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, channel.getExitStatus() returning -1 means the process has not finished yet.  Are you sure you're giving the process enough time to execute and finish?  You didn't include the code to convertISToString(is) so maybe that's handling things correctly but, just in case, from the JSch Exec.java example, one way of waiting for it to finish properly and get an exit code is to do something like:

```
while(true){
  while(in.available()>0){
    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
    if(i<0)break;
    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
  }
  if(channel.isClosed()){
    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
    break;
  }
  try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experiment, the code `exitCode = channel.getExitStatus();` will return 0 if the command sent to the channel produce text as a result, such as `pwd` or `ECHO a`. When the command doesn't return any text, `exitCode` will return -1, but it doesn't mean that it failed to execute.